# Simulate key press in Ubuntu Terminal without using xdtool or similar

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, simulate

i want to run a command and then "tell" the command line to press the letter "M"

but i cant use tools like xdtool or extra software.

example:
top -n 1
and then M (press)

anyone knows?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no simple, built-in way to script an interactive tool like top; in particular `top -n 1` exits immediately, so it wouldn't listen to the "M" command anyway.

However, if what you want is a list of which programs are using the most memory, you can use the non-interactive `ps` tool to generate a list in whatever order you like. For example, here's a command that will show you the top-5 programs by memory-usage:

```
ps -A -o %mem,args --sort -%mem | head -6
```

`-A` means ps will examine all running processes.

`-o %mem,args` means that ps will print the `%mem` (memory used as a percentage of total memory) and `args` (full command-line including arguments) of each process it examines.

`--sort -%mem` means that ps will sort the results by the `%mem` column in descending order (ascending order would be `--sort %mem`).

`| head -6` means the output will be piped through the `head` command, configured to show the first 6 lines of output (a line of headers, plus the first five processes in the list).